# is it possible to only apply dir="ltr" to some specific divs?

Tags: html, right-to-left

I have a page that need to display text from Right to Left. So I added a `dir="rtl"` in the `<html>` tag. Everything works fine for years until I need to add some specific HTML in the page while that HTML elements should not work fine with `dir="rtl"` attribute on. I try to add `dir` attribute to that div element as `<div dir="ltr">` but I figure out that causes the whole page turns into Left to Right mode.

Is there anything I can specify some specific HTML elements with the ltr direction mode when the page has a `<html dir="rtl" ...` applied?

Thanks,

Update:

Try this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html dir="rtl">
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.ex1 {direction:ltr;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>Some text. Default writing direction.</div>
<div class="ex1">Some text. Right-to-left direction.</div>

</body>
</html>
```

In this example, the `Some text. Default writing direction` should be from R2L, but it's actually L2R even if the class `.ex1` is only applied to the second `<div>` tag.

Comment: Adding rtl to specific input fields/divs should only affect those and not the entire document. At least that's how it did for me.

Comment: @Allan I've updated the question, please take a look. Thanks

Comment: How did you infer what the writing direction is? The example contains only English text, and except in special cases, such text is not affected by the writing direction.

Comment: The code in the question does not show any attribute on the `html` element. It has a malformed `doctype` string; such strings cannot contain any attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using css

example:

```
div{direction:rtl;}
```

**[LINK](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_text_direction)**

**Update:**

try this css:

```
div {direction:rtl;}
div.ex1 {direction:ltr;}
```

**[LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/Qcbbt/)**

Comment: I've updated the question, please take a look. Thanks